# How to bind data.json file to Kendo UI chart in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am trying to binding JSON data to Kendo UI charts in ASP.Net MVC. I looked through many documentations but couldn't find the right solution for me. I hope someone here can help me!

This is the **JSON** data:

```
[
  {
    "SubjectId": 60369,
    "SubjectName": "Mathematics",
    "Score": 50.00,
    "RemainingScore": 50.00,
    "SubjectColor": "#ffa620",
    "SortOrder": 1
  },
  {
    "SubjectId": 61529,
    "SubjectName": "Biology",
    "Score": 30.00,
    "RemainingScore": 70.00,
    "SubjectColor": "#e082fb",
    "SortOrder": 1
  },
  {
    "SubjectId": 60812,
    "SubjectName": "Chemistry",
    "Score": 50.00,
    "RemainingScore": 50.00,
    "SubjectColor": "#ac97fb",
    "SortOrder": 2
  }
]
```

Here is **MODEL**:

```
public class ScoreModel
{        
    public int SubjectId { get; set; }
    public string SubjectName { get; set; }
    public double Score { get; set; }
    public double RemainingScore { get; set; }
    public string SubjectColor { get; set; }
    public int SortOrder { get; set; }
}
```

Here is **VIEW**:

```
@model IEnumerable<BarChart.Models.ScoreModel>
@(Html.Kendo().Chart(Model)
        .Name("chart")
        .Title("SUBJECT SCORE")
        .Theme("Flat")
        .Legend(legend => legend.Visible(false))
        .DataSource(ds => ds.Read(read => read.Action("LoadJson", "Home")))
        .Series(series =>
        {
            series.Bar(model => model.Score, model=> model.SubjectColor)
                .CategoryField("SubjectName")
                .Labels(labels => labels.Visible(true)
                    .Format("{0}%")
                    .Position(ChartBarLabelsPosition.OutsideEnd));
        })
        .CategoryAxis(axis => axis
            .MajorGridLines(lines => lines.Visible(false))
        )
        .ValueAxis(axis => axis.Numeric()
            .Labels(labels => labels.Visible(false))
            .Line(lines => lines.Visible(true))
            .MajorGridLines(lines => lines.Visible(false))
        )
        .Tooltip(tooltip => tooltip
            .Visible(true).Template("#= series.name #: #= value #")
        )

    )
```

AND here is **CONTROLLER**:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
       return View();
}
public void LoadJson()
{
      using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(@"D:\Projects\BarChart\ScoreData.json"))
      {
           string json = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
           List<ScoreModel> items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ScoreModel>>(json);
      }
}
```

I also don't know how to return **json** data to **view**. Please help me out with that too. I am new to .NET and still have a lot to learn.